# How can I implement an ordered array with mongodb without race-conditions?

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I'm new to mongodb, maybe this is a trivial question.  I have two mongodb collections: `user` and `post`.  A user can create and follow multiple posts, and posts are listed sorted by last modification date.  There may be a very large number of users following a specific post, so I don't want to keep the list of followers in each post document.  On the other hand, one user will probably not follow more than a few thousand posts, so I decided to keep the list of followed posts' objectids in each user document.

In order to be able to quickly list the 50 most recently modified posts for a given user, I chose to keep the `last_updated_at` field along with the post objectid.

The `post` document is fairly basic:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e847"),
    "title" : "All about music"
    "comments": [...]
    ...
}
```

The `user` document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e846"),
  "posts": [{
    "post": ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e847"),
    "last_updated_at": ISODate("2013-04-09T11:27:07.184Z")
  }, {
    "post": ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e847"),
    "last_updated_at": ISODate("2013-04-09T11:27:07.187Z")
  }]
  ...
}
```

When a user creates or follows a post, I can simply `$push` the post's `ObjectId` and `last_updated_at` to the end of the `posts` list in the user's document.  When a post is modified (for example when a comment is added to the post), I update the `last_updated_at` field for that post in all the follower's user documents.  That's pretty heavy, but I don't know how to avoid it.

When I want to get the list of 50 most recently updated posts for a user, I unfortunately need to get the whole list of followed posts, then sort by `last_updated_at` in memory, then keep only the first 50 posts.

So I tried to change the implementation to reorder the list when a post is modified: I `$push` it to the end of the list, and `$pull` it from wherever it is.  Since this is a two step procedure, there's a race condition where I might get twice the same post in the list.  Is there no better way to maintain a sorted array in mongodb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Data model adjustment

Since you may have frequent updates to the latest posts for a given user, you probably want to avoid the overhead of rewriting data unnecessarily to maintain a sorted array.

A better approach to consider would be to flatten the data model and use a separate collection instead of an ordered array:

- create a separate collection with the updated post stream: `(userID, postID, lastUpdated)`
- when a post is updated, you can then do a simple [`update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with the `multi:true` and `upsert:true` options and `$set` the last_updated_at to the new value.
- to retrieve the last 50 updated posts for a given userID you can do a normal `find()` with sort and limit options.
- to automatically clean up the "old" documents you could even set a [TTL expiry](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) for this collection so the updates are removed from the activity stream after a certain number of days

#### Pushing to fixed-size & sorted arrays in MongoDB 2.4

If you do want to maintain ordered arrays, MongoDB 2.4 added two helpful features related to this use case:

- Ability to push to fixed-sized arrays
- Ability to push to arrays sorted by embedded document fields

So you can achieve your outcome of pushing to a fixed-sized array of 50 items sorted by last updated date descending:

```
db.user.update(
    // Criteria
    { _id: ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e846") },

    // Update
    { $push: {
        posts: {
            // Push one or more updates onto the posts array
            $each: [
                {
                    "post": ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e847"),
                    "last_updated_at": ISODate()
                }
            ],

            // Slice to max of 50 items
            $slice:-50,

            // Sorted by last_updated_at desc
            $sort: {'last_updated_at': -1}
        }
    }}
)
```

The `$push` will update the list in sorted order, with the `$slice` trimming the list to the first 50 items.  Since the posts aren't unique you'll still need to `$pull` the original from the list first, eg:

```
db.user.update(
    // Criteria
    { _id: ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e846") },

    // Update
    { 
        $pull: {
            posts: { post: ObjectId("5163deebe4d809d55d27e847") }
        }
    }
)
```

A benefit of this approach is that array manipulation is being done on the server, but as with sorting the array in your application you may still be updating the document more than is required.

Comment: +1 This is great, thanks.  Just one problem though: when a post is modified, I need to find it in the user's `posts` list and update its `last_updated_at` field.  Will this automagically atomically reorder the list?

Comment: If not, I suppose I should delete it from the list and immediately add it again (or vice-versa).  There will be a small delay during which the `posts` list will not be consistent, won't there?

Comment: @MiniQuark: reconsidered the approach given the need to $pull/$push and the frequency of updates.  A more efficient approach would be to flatten the data model and avoid maintaining the ordered array .. have updated accordingly ;-).

Comment: This is excellent advice, thanks a lot. If I could +2, I would. :-))